# Quiero obtener la posición de una celda cuando doy click en ella

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, matriz

Como podría obtener la posición de una celda al hacer click en ella, he coseguido pasarle el numero con las props, y lo que he hecho ha sido colocar un enlace y añadirle el atributo onClick pero no consigue que funcione, tengo algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría que cuando haga click en la pizza muestre la posición x e y de esa celda y poner esos valores en un label aqui:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué fallo te da? ¿Aparece algo en la consola?

Comment: El problema es que se ejecuta todo el rato sin que yo tenga que hacer click

Comment: Añade el código como texto, no como imagen. Es complicado leer y es imposible copiar a una respuesta tu código si no es así. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y mejorarla, haciéndola más "accesible"

Comment: Estás ejecutando la función en lugar de asignarla, prueba con `onClick = {() => handleClick(props)}`

Comment: Perfecto, ahora si funciona @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás ejecutando la función en lugar de asignarla, prueba con onClick = {() => handleClick(props)} – Pablo Lozano